# How bluetooth headset send voice to android phone, if android phones are uniquely A2DP source devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How bluetooth headset send voice to android device, if android phones are uniquely A2DP source devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that Android devices only support A2DP. Most, if not all(?) Android devices with Bluetooth support the Hands-free Profile, where voice audio is transferred between the device and the accessory over a SCO link.

If your question actually was *"I've got an Android device that only supports A2DP, can I use it for voice calls over Bluetooth?"* then I don't know. I suspect not, since A2DP is unidirectional.